# Iterate every csv column and predict value using linear regression

Tags: python, loops, csv, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am using a loop to grab values from every csv row and run it through *linear_regression_model* for prediction. The needed output is, **for every row in the csv, print the predicted value that ran through the model**, like:

```
4.500
4.256
3.909
4.565
...
4.433
```

Here is what I did:

```
def prediction_loop():
    for index, row in ml_sample.iterrows():
        print(row['column'])
        new_data = OrderedDict(['column', row])
        new_data = pd.Series(new_data).values.reshape(1,-1)
        print(linear_regression_model.predict(new_data))
```

The actual output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
new_data = OrderedDict(['column', row])
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

In the csv there are 87 rows and 1 column.
How can I optimise the code?
Thank you

Comment: So it's not really a CSV file is it? It's just a flat file with a number on each line

Comment: a DataFrame containing a list of values on each line, also yes. It's imported from a csv with one column only. Is that the mistake I am making you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then this can be done very efficiently without the aid of any external modules. We just need a trivial class to manage the statistics. The assumption is that the input file contains one numerical value per line and that such values are Y and the implied line number is X. Try this:-

```
class Stats():
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
        self.sx = 0
        self.sy = 0
        self.sxx = 0
        self.syy = 0
        self.sxy = 0

    def add(self, x, y):
        self.sx += x
        self.sy += y
        self.sxx += x * x
        self.syy += y * y
        self.sxy += x * y
        self.n += 1

    def r(self):  # correlation coefficient
        return (self.n * self.sxy - self.sx * self.sy) / ((self.n * self.sxx - self.sx * self.sx) * (self.n * self.syy - self.sy * self.sy)) ** 0.5

    def b(self):  # slope
        return (self.n * self.sxy - self.sx * self.sy) / (self.n * self.sxx - self.sx * self.sx)

    def a(self):  # intercept
        return self.my() - self.b() * self.mx()

    def mx(self):  # mean x
        assert self.n > 0
        return self.sx / self.n

    def my(self):  # mean y
        assert self.n > 0
        return self.sy / self.n

    def y(self, x):  # estimate of y for given x
        return x * self.b() + self.a()


stats = Stats()

with open('lr.txt') as data:
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        stats.add(i, float(line.split()[0]))

print(f'r={stats.r():.4f} slope={stats.b():.4f} intercept={stats.a():.4f}')

for x in range(stats.n):
    print(f'Estimate for {x} = {stats.y(x):.2f}')
```